# how to clear +(UIImage *) from memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

is it possible to clear memory of the following sample code?

```
+(UIImage *) makeGray:(UIImage *) image {
     // Transform UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat imageMat;
    UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

    //Transform image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //draw contour
    if(shape[i].size() >0 && ....)
    {
     drawContours(....)

      //get largest contour
       if(a > largetest_area)
      {
        largest_area = a;
        largest_contour_index = i;
        bounding_rect = boundingRect(contours[i]);
        largest_contour_value = boundingRect(contours[largetst_contour_index])

    return MatToUIImage(grayMat);
}
```

I tried to `grayMat.release()` without success.
looks like I could `delete[] 'function name';` however, I couldn't call the function.

Comment: Why do you assume the objects wouldn’t clean up after themselves?

Comment: Does it clean up automatically?
I am debugging the code using Xcode debug and Instruments. It seems like the CPU usage and phone temperature rises rapidly over time.

Comment: That's Objective-C

Comment: You've posted Objective-C code. Why do you have the `swift` tag on your question?

Answer (score 0):

Memory problems don’t show as CPU usage. Use Instruments.app with the "Leaks" Template to find memory problems and the "Profiler" to find performance problems.